# Appropriate iptables rules for an FTP server in active \ passive mode

Tags: linux, ftp, iptables, centos6, proftpd

I installed a ProFTPD server on a CentOS6.
If i make ftp localhost, i can connect correctly, but if i try from outside, i obtain the message "no route to host". But there is a route to host because i am connected via SSH.

I tried adding the following iptable rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"

iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"

iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
```

and restarted both proftpd and iptables services.
What can i do to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to allow FTP you need the following rules on the server:

1. Allow control connections initiated by the client to port 21, as follows:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 21"
   ```
2. For active mode, allow data connections initiated by the server from port 20, as follows:

   ```
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
   iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow ftp connections on port 20"
   ```
3. For passive mode, allow data connections initiated by the client on unprivileged ports:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections"
   ```

The ordinary `conntrack` modules should correctly track when a `RELATED` data connection is established in active mode, however you might need to load the `nf_conntrack_ftp` module for correctly tracking when such connections are established in passive mode:

- Check if it's loaded with `lsmod | grep nf_conntrack_ftp`.
- Load it with `modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp`.

Alternatively, you may replace the `RELATED` state with the `NEW` state, which is less secure, but would definitely get the job done.

[This link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) supplies a concise summary of the rationale for the above rules.

Comment: It seems to me that the default `conntrack` module isn't able to track `RELATED` outgoing packages for passive mode. Enabling `nf_conntrack_ftp` resolved the connection tracking.